# Deriving mathematical solutions from Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams

So I know that we can represent mathematical expressions using Feynman diagrams, however, I wonder if we could derive mathematical solutions from a Feynman diagram.

For example, if we have the Feynman diagram shown below:

[image]

How would I use each part of the diagram to derive a complete mathematical solution representing the diagram?

Comment: (this diagram denotes Deep Inelastic Scattering. This should be covered in most QFT textbooks, e.g. chapter 32 in Schwarz)

Comment: -1 this can be found in Larkoski

Comment: Additionally to @Frederic Thomas' great answer, I would like to refer to a question of mine, which resulted in a reference to graphical calculations with Feynman diagrams [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/734788/209401).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculus of Feynman diagrams](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/734561/)

Answer (score 2):

You asking something which would require half or even one year of QFT lecture.
To make it short, sure there are clear mathematical rules to compute the probability amplitude of Feynman diagrams. However, all the ingredients for the computation --- even without any explanation why they have to be used -- are rather complex mathematical objects which each need a lengthy explanation.
For the computation of the probability amplitude of a tree-like diagram as the one shown three components are needed: 2 fermonic currents and the propagator for the exchange particle:

$$\cal{M} = \text{electron current}(k,k')\times photon\, propagator \times \text{hadronic(proton) current}(p,p')$$

The eletron current can be rather easily computed based on the Dirac equation for electrons, whereas the hadronic current is very complicated as the proton is a composite particle. It actually requires the knowledge of the distribution of the quarks inside the proton, which is given by the structure functions.

However, in case of low energy, when the transferred energy and momentum is small, i.e. the Compton wave length  of the proton is much smaller than the inverse of the transferred energy (scaled by speed of light and Planck's constant)  simpler approximations are possible, where the proton can be considered as particle essentially without inner structure, but doted by an electric and magnetic form factor.  In that case the Rosenbluth formula can be applied to compute the cross section.